# DatagridViewButtonColumn Text Displaying Only in Editing Mode? Why?

Tags: c#

In my Datagridview, I have a button column. I want to display text on my button. It displays text only when I enter a text into another row of the datagridview. It does not display it when the form is run.
I use this code to assign text to the button.

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn dgv_col22 = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
dgv_col22.Text = "delete‌";
dgv_col22.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
```

Is there another way to do that?
I use Visual Studio 2013 Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn dgv_col22 = new DataGridViewButtonColumn()
{
    dgv_col22.Text = "delete‌",
    dgv_col22.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true
}
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgv_col22);
```